# Knowing CSS property with contenteditable

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have a box with `contenteditable=true` which contains multiple css style (bold,italic, ...).

If i write near bold text, the new text will be written in bold too. Is there any way to know, with Javascript, which properties will be applied to the text?

**Edit:**

Here is a small example with JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WgCBZ/

If i write in or after the bold text, i'll write in bold, if i write in or after the no style text, i'll write without style.

I'd like to know the style of the text that will be written on key press.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) { 
  // Find the style
  // If bold will be written alert "bold"
  // If italic will be written alert "italic"
  // else alert ""
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML along with the corresponding CSS and describe somewhat more exactly, what you want to achieve, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find if a particular command is currently enabled for a target using `queryCommandState`, which will return the boolean for the command of the current state of the target.

```
if(document.queryCommandState('bold')){
  // The target (cursor) is currently bold
}
```

You can find the commands available in a `contenteditable` on MDN at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla